# Deleting command messages after sending them

Tags: c#, discord.net

I started to write my own bot for a discord server using Discord.net. I already made the first command (which still doesn't work correctly, but that's for another story), and now that I am testing, it has a chat full of commands I sent. My goal is to instantly delete those messages as I send them (let's say I send **.command something**, and this should appear in a chat just for a little moment). I tried to look it up in documentation and some tutorials but couldn't find anything. I have only basic knowledge of programming, so I would be happy if you could tell me how to achieve this and explain how it works.

Comment: `await Context.Message.DeleteAsync()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question of how to delete a message, you use the `Context.Channel.DeleteMessageAsync` function. It takes a message id as the parameter, so you will need to have the message data in memory at the time.

To answer the question of how to delete a message that you have just sent, you can use the above delete function alongside the `Context.Message` data which gives you the message data of the message that triggered the command. It will look like the following:

```
[Command("TestDelete")]
public async TestDeleteCommand()
{
   await Context.Channel.DeleteMessageAsync(Context.Message.Id);
}
```

You can find more information of the DeleteMessageAsync function by looking at the [Discord.Net docs](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.ISocketMessageChannel.html)

Comment: Also, if you have access to the message object, you can use `Message.DeleteAsync()`. Because [Message](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketMessage.html) inherits from [IDeletable](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.IDeletable.html)

Comment: That is exactly what i could not find. Thank you very much.